# Actions of semisimple groups on semisimple tensor categories

Tags: rt.representation-theory, ct.category-theory

Let $G$ be a connected semi-simple algebraic group,
and
 let $\mathcal C^{\otimes}=(\mathcal C,\otimes)$ be a semi-simple tensor category (let's say just monoidal, althought I'de be happy to have an answer in the braided case too):

> Is it possible for $G$ to act non-trivially on $\mathcal C^{\otimes}$ by tensor auto-equivalences?

The answer to the above question is, perhaps surprisingly, **yes**:
Take the category $\mathcal C$ to be the direct sum over $N\in\mathbb N$ of $\operatorname{Rep}(\mathit{Cliff}(nN))=\operatorname{Rep}(\mathit{Cliff}(n)^{\otimes N})$.
[Added after Theo JF's comment: this example is in the world of super-vector spaces.]
The group $\operatorname{SO}(n)$ acts non-trivially by tensor auto-equivalences.
(One can even make sense of the direct sum over $N\in\mathbb Z$ if one cares)

So let me add the requirement that the action of $G$ on the underlying linear category $\mathcal C$ is trivial.

> Is it then possible for $G$ to act non-trivially on $\mathcal C^{\otimes}$ by tensor auto-equivalences?

I can also be more concrete:
If the action of $G$ on the underlying linear category $\mathcal C$ to be trivial, then here's what's left:
For every triple of objects $a,b,c\in \mathcal C$, an action of $G$ on the finite dimensional vector space $Hom(a\otimes b,c)$. Those actions should be natural in $a$, $b$, and $c$, and satisfy a certain coherence relation which says that the two ways of getting an action on $Hom(a\otimes b\otimes c, d)$ should agree.

Comment: Is one discussing here an algebraic action (and, if so, what does that mean when $\operatorname{Aut}(\mathcal C^\otimes)$ isn't obviously (to me) an algebraic group?), or an abstract action of an appropriate group of rational points (and, if so, rational over what?)?

Comment: The tensor autoequivalences of $\mathcal{C}$ are not just a group but a 2-group, and one could imagine a map $G \to Aut_\otimes(\mathcal{C})$ which is trivial on homotopy but still nontrivial at the level of 2-groups. In particular, I think that $\pi_1 Aut_\otimes(\mathcal{C})$ are the monoidal natural automorphisms of $\mathrm{id}_{\mathcal{C}}$, and I know plenty of examples where this is, say, $\mathbb{Z}/2$, and where $G$ admits a $\mathbb{Z}/2$ central extension.

Comment: Not knowing exactly whether you mean super representations of a super algebra or what, it seems like in your example your monoidal category is the "tensor algebra" on Rep(Cliff(n)). The monoidal SO(n)-action on the whole category should then be determined by the non-monoidal action on Rep(Cliff(n)), and I guess this is an example of my question: each element of SO(n) acts trivializably, but there is a nontrivial extension to Spin(n) encoded by the map of 2-groups SO(n) $\to$ Aut(Rep(Cliff(n))).

Comment: Do you have an almost-example that fails only because $\mathcal{C}$ is non-semisimple? If so, you can try to semisimplify it, eg by using https://arxiv.org/abs/1801.04409.

Comment: @TheoJohnson-Freyd. No, I don't know of any examples. I would just like to know that such actions can never exist (and I'm afraid that they might exist).